# Quantifying how underdetermined a system of equations or optimization problem is

Tags: optimization, linear-algebra, underdetermined

In linear systems we have an exact solution when we have as many equations as unknowns and the equations are linearly independent, e.g.,
$$
x_0 + 2 x_1 = 5 \\
x_0 + 3 x_1 = 7 \\
$$
has the unique solution $x = (1, 2)$.

In many real-world cases we have underdetermined systems with more unknowns than equations, e.g.,
$$
x_0 + 2 x_1 + 3 x_2 + 4 x_3 = 5 \\
x_0 + 3 x_1 + 3 x_2 + 4 x_3 = 7 \\
$$
but we often impose some external cost function (e.g., maximum likelihood) to pick the best of the infinite number of solutions,
$$
x^* = \text{argmin}_x f(x).
$$
As a toy example, consider the squared loss function $f(x) = x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2$. It gives the minimum-loss solution of $x^* = (1/26, 2, 3/26, 4/26)$.

Now consider adding the equation
$$
x_0 = 1/26 + 10^{-6}
$$
or alternatively the equation
$$
x_0^2 = 1/26^2
$$

Roughly speaking, neither of these equations *really* adds much information. Sure, they may change $x^*$ slightly, but not by much. These equations may add *some* information, but not enough to shift the parameters much or even produce a fully-determined system of equations.

In the general case, we have an underdetermined system of (potentially non-linear) equations subject to our minimum cost criterion $\text{argmin}_x f(x)$, but end up finding that in some sense, many of the rows of $A$ are degenerate, or nearly so, adding very little useful information to the minimization. Is there then some continuous metric (perhaps based in information theory) by which we can quantify the degeneracy or underdeterminedness of the matrix $A$, analogous to the number of linearly independent rows in the exact solution case?

Answer (score 1):

There is a metric that describes something that we could consider an *underdeterminedness* of a matrix - its [Condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number). It describes how much the output is sensitive to changes in input and it can be e.g. used to discover multicollinearity in your data.

Assume you want to find $x$ given $A, b$:
$$
Ax = b
$$
Now, say that, because of some measurement error you measure $b + \Delta b$. This will have an effect of $x + \Delta x$ on your solution. We have:
$$
A(x + \Delta x) = (b + \Delta b) \implies Ax + A\Delta x = b + \Delta b \implies A\Delta x = \Delta b \implies \Delta x = A^{-1} \Delta b
$$
if $A^{-1}$ is invertible. *Condition number* is a maximum value a ratio of *relative* change in $x$ (i.e. $\frac{\Vert \Delta x \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert}$) and a relative change in $b$ (i.e. $\frac{\Vert \Delta b \Vert}{\Vert b \Vert}$):
$$
c = max \Bigl( \frac{\frac{\Vert \Delta x \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert}}{\frac{\Vert \Delta b \Vert}{\Vert b \Vert}} \Bigl)
$$
which you can [prove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) to be equal to $c = \Vert A \Vert \Vert A^{-1} \Vert$ (where $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ denotes Euclidean $L^2$ norm)

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was thinking, but in my case, the system is truly underdetermined---$A$ has more columns than rows i.e. more unknowns than equations. Therefore it has no inverse $A^{-1}$. It is only the minimum cost (e.g. maximum likelihood) condition that picks out one particular solution. Could the condition number somehow be extended to this case?

Comment: You can [generalize](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/375512/581561) condition number to rectangular matrices as it can be expressed as a ratio of singular values which can be done for singular matrices.